# Inject VBA code into an Excel resource file

Tags: c#, excel

Supposing that I have a C# project that has an Excel Workbook as resource, containing some generic VBA modules.

I need to serve that file after injecting some VBA code that is specific to the client. What librairies would you recommend to do this and do you have experience of these for such purpose ?

And as an additional question, is there any tool for C# that permits to run macros while the workbook is in memory ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Write the resource to disk, load it via Excel interop then you can manipulate the macros via VBProject.VBComponents http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of this via `Excel Interop` and `VBE Interop`

I add in the VBA component as follows:

```
        ExcelApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule).CodeModule.AddFromFile(...)
```

Then I run it as follows:

```
        ExcelApp.Run(YOUR MACRO NAME)
```